Cannot install Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on Legion 5 15ACH6H
When I try to upgrade from inside nothing really happens.
I've tried:

Changing the download archives
Changing the mode from standard to LTS

On the terminal I get the message saying there are no versions I can upgrade to.
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on a pen and I'm trying to do a clean install.
When I try to test or install I get a display with nothing.
When I try the graphics safe option I get the error:
Invalid argument
mount: mounting /dev/loop1 on /minimal.standard.squashfs failed: Invalid argument
Can not mount /dev/loop1 (/cdrom/casper/minimal.standard.squashfs) on /minimal.standard.squashfs

This happens both with and without Secure Boot.
There are some other errors that happen when booting the current installation, but I don't know if they relate to this problem.
Changing the usb drive I was using solved the issue.

Use another pendrive and recreate the installer.

Have you tried pressing Windows (Super) key (Or click on "show applications") and search for and use "software updater"?

@kyodake this worked, thanks!

@stumblebee yes I had done that, both through applications and do-release-upgrade

@Miguel Rodriguez: The message corresponds to a damaged installation media.
